# Getting random http/s requests from certain IP addresses

Tags: nginx, ubuntu, docker, digital-ocean, network-security

Stack used: **ExpressJs, NodeJs, Docker, Nginx, Ubuntu 20.04**

I host my backend on **DigitalOcean droplet** with the tech stack mentioned above. My server constantly has been targeted multiple times on specific http/s requests trying to read sometimes sensitive information (such as env files). Those requests are coming from local network (::ffff:192.168.128.6) as well as from the public. For example:

```
 1. /wp-admin/.env
 2. /api.mydomain.com/.env
 3. /library/.env
 4. /new/.env
 5. /old/.env
 6. /local/.env
 7. /app/config/.env
 8. /api/.env
 9. /conf/.env
 10. /database/.env
 11. /vendor/phpunit/src/Util/PHP/eval-stdin.php
 12. /showLogin.cc
 13. ... not the full list ...
```

The good news are that all the requests are ending with **404 status code** but I'm not sure if they haven't succeeded to retrieve something yet...

Is there a way of **securing my server**?

I've done an update to my security server by recording all of ip address trying to hit wrong url and sending me email with wrong url and IP address, is there something I can do to block those ip address on my server's machine so that they can't make any type of request?

I tried to:

```
ufw insert 1 reject from IP_ADDRESS to any
```

I also tried to set the deny IP_ADDRESS in nginx config:

```
server { 
        include /var/www/blocked_ips.conf;

        listen                  443 ssl;
        listen                  [::]:443 ssl;
        server_name             api.mydomain-staging.com;

        server_tokens off;
        
        ...rest of the code
}
```

This is blocked_ips.conf file:

```
deny IP_1;
deny IP_2;
deny IP_3;
```

But this approaches don't seem to work.

UPD looks like the DigitalOcean itself is targeting my server, how is that possible? What should I do?

[image]

How can I reject any kind of access on network level (rather than nginx or nodejs level) from certain IP addresses?
Thank you mates in advance!

Comment: `ufw insert 1 reject from IP_ADDRESS to any` should do it - what makes you think it's not working? (I'd use `deny` instead of `reject`)

Comment: As for the last about Digital Ocean itself - you do realise that you aren't the only person hosting with Digital Ocean, right? Also, is 143.198.193.122 your IP or the one "targetting" you (you forgot to mask the Decimal version of the IP address)

Answer (score 4):

Welcome to the Internet where this is normal: all kind of crawlers and bots are constantly searching for vulnerabilities & information that should not be publicly available.

The approach of blocking IP addresses is problematic:

- It will not stop that type of traffic.
- You may end up blocking legitimate visitors if

  - they share the same IP (NAT, proxy, VPN) or
  - your bans are infinite.

#### What is your risk model?

Securing your server is not about blocking these request. Instead, you should have a risk model:

1. What (bad) could happen?
2. What is the probability of that?
3. What would be the consequences?
4. How to address that risk?

If we answer those question with the concerns from your question:

1. Bad people could scan my server for sensitive data.
2. 100 %.
3. It depends on what kind of vulnerabilities or sensitive data there is.
4. ???

That does not help much, does it? But you could also rephrase it to describe the actual risks:

1. Someone (or some software) could unintentionally left behind an `.env` file that could have sensitive information like passwords in it.
2. *Your own estimate of the likelihood based on how many people are developing & administering the system, what kind of tools they use for that, has it happened before etc.*
3. Someone could find the file and use that information for, e.g.,  accessing our systems without permission.
4. Block access to `.env` files. Regularly search the file system for such files in directories that are publicly available.

With Nginx you could block access to all `.env` files with:

```
location ~* /\.env$ {
  deny all;
}
```

#### Web Application Firewalls (WAF)

The configuration for blocking certain patterns is simple. The real struggle is that there are too many patterns to think of. Luckily, there are collections of typical attack patterns. On Nginx you could use, e.g., [ModSecurity](https://github.com/SpiderLabs/ModSecurity-nginx) (an open source WAF) & [OWASP ModSecurity Core Rule Set](https://owasp.org/www-project-modsecurity-core-rule-set/) which is such a collection.

#### Fail2Ban

If you really want to ban IP addresses, you should do it automatically and temporarily. [Fail2Ban](https://github.com/fail2ban/fail2ban) is a common tool for that. It is typically used for banning hosts with multiple authentication failures to slow down brute-force login attacks. Likewise, it could be set up to monitor logs for messages from ModSecurity. The Internet is full of tutorials (search for, e.g., `Fail2Ban ModSecurity Nginx`).